# Creating a data structure that will hold objects in React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm building a program in React that is basically a questionnaire / survey, so far I've got users answering a bunch of questions then what I am trying to do is take the answers, filter them a bit then return an object to store using Redux. Each question is an object it self that holds different factors than I am trying to measure. Although, I'm getting stuck with actually trying to create the structure of the final object.

I want the object to look something like this:

```
Results {
   Question1 {
     factor1: 1,
     factor2: 2,
     factor3: 3
   },
   Question2 {
     factor1: 3,
     factor2: 6
   }, 
   and so on...
}
```

But when I try create create it by saying for example

```
let results = {
   Question1 {
      factor1: 0
   }
}
```

React doesn't like it. As soon as I try nest another object inside it returns an error.. Am I missing something simple or do I need to try another approach, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like this, property and value needs to be separated by a :

```
let results = {
  Question1 :{
     factor1: 0
  }
}

let Results= {
   Question1: {
     factor1: 1,
     factor2: 2,
     factor3: 3
   },
   Question2: {
     factor1: 3,
     factor2: 6
   }, 
   and so on...
}
```